# xslt unterminated string constant error

Tags: string, xslt, constants

for the expression

```
<h1 title="{title}: {short-description}">
```

if the title contains a single quote in the value, this throws unterminated string constant error . How can i fix this error?

Thanks in advance
Alex.

Comment: **No-repro**. This input `<title>'</title>` with this stylesheet `<h1 title="{title}"
    xsl:version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xsl:exclude-result-prefixes="xsl"/>` output `<h1 title="'" />`

Comment: Like Alejandro said, I can't reproduce this error either. I tried Xalan, Saxon 6.5.5, and Saxon 9.3. Are you sure the error isn't because the `h1` element isn't closed? What processor are you using and what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to have that as

```
<h1 title="{title}: {short-description}">
    ... some value here for the h1 to display ...
</h1>
```

Alternatively you could do the following:

```
<xsl:element name="h1">
    <xsl:attribute name="title">
        {title}: {short-description}
    </xsl:attribute>
    ... some value here for the h1 to display ...
</xsl:element>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The first form has nothing to do with the second. Read about [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates).

Comment: Thanks Dave for the reply. My problem here is this expression {title} is giving me a value with a single quote. eg: testing' . now when the expression gets evaluated we will be having an element with unterminated string. How can i change this to accomodate those values also. (values with quotes)

Comment: If this code is failing because of the content of the title element, then there is a bug in your processor. Please show a complete working example (source document plus stylesheet) and say which XSLT processor you are using.